# Python: After making a work-around for an EOFError, code doesn't ask for input in second run of a while loop

Tags: python, input, while-loop

Little context: I'm working with a Zumi (physical toy car that can be programmed with Python)

However, this issue pertains to threading, looping, and inputs. All my threading works fine. However, a specific while loop acts weirdly after the first iteration.

```
from zumi.zumi import Zumi
import threading, time, sys

zumi = Zumi()

def commands(star):

    global comm

    print("thread 1 started")
    time.sleep(1)

    while star == "t":
        try:
            inp = str(input("Command: ")) <---
            if inp.lower() == "d":
                comm = "d"
            elif inp.lower() == "r":
                comm = "r"
            elif inp.lower() == "p":
                comm = "p"
            elif inp.lower() == "b":
                print("Killing Zumi")
                zumi.stop()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                print("I don't understand.")
        except EOFError as e:
            print(end = "")
            inp = ""

def constacheck(star):

    global comm

    print("thread 2 started")

    while star == "t":
        if comm == "d":
            forwards()
        elif comm == "r":
            backwards()
        elif comm == "p":
            parallel()

star = "t"
inp = ""
comm = ""

print("create and start thread 1")
x = threading.Thread(target=commands, args=(star))
x.start()

time.sleep(1)

print("create and start thread 2")
z = threading.Thread(target=constacheck, args=(star))
z.start()
```

I put an arrow which points to the area of interest. The first time I run the code, I am asked for the input, and it does everything correctly. However, immediately afterwards, it should ask for the same input, and change the variables according (which will them affect my second loop- constacheck). Instead it returns an EOFError: Error when reading a line, which I solved by making the code repeat the loop, ignoring the error. However, every loop afterwards raises the same error, and thus creates a constant loop of printing "Command: "

It looks something like this:

```
Command: d
Driving forwards.
Command: Command: Command: Command: Command: Command: Driving forward.Command: Command: Command: Command: Command: Command: Command: Driving forward.
```

*etc.*

How do I stop the EOFError, and every time the while loop in commands() loops, ask for an input?
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using EOFError as the exception?  Also, what are those other functions (```forwards```, ```backwards``` and ```parallel```) like?

Comment: @ewong I looked up solutions to EOFErrors, and this solution allowed the code to keep running, even after the error. Those functions simply print `Driving forward.` `Driving backward.` `Parallel Parking.`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error on my computer. Are you getting the error when you run the code on the toy car?

Comment: @sommervold I am getting the error when I run the full code. I tried running the while loop separate from everything else, and it worked. However, with both threads running at the same time, once it reaches the input again, it creates an EOFError.